# Ruby: FileUtils.cp_r and invalid multibyte character exception

Tags: ruby

When using FileUtils.cp_r i'm getting the following exception:

```
 invalid multibyte character
 /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:1503:in `descendant_diretory?'
```

Inside the directory that i'm copying, there is another directory with some special characters. But i think that Ruby should deal with it as running the cp shell command works fine.

Any ideas of how to make Ruby ignore this exception and finish the directory copy?

Thanks.

Comment: try to experiment with `Encoding.default_internal` & `Encoding.default_external`

Comment: Works fine in Ruby 1.9.3-p327. Tried to copy a folder named `source` which had another folder inside it named `testÎÍ„´ÎÍÍ„„„´ÎÍÎÍte` and it copied it.

Answer (score 0):

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

on top of your ruby script.

https://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding solves most of the encoding issues with ruby!

Comment: Thanks but the exception happens inside Ruby's core, in fileutils.rb.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned `# encoding: ...` will only work when the data in question comes from the source of the script, which is not the case here.

The exception happens because the name of the directory cannot be represented in the external encoding (which is most likely UTF-8, inherited from the program's environment).

As zed_0xff points out, one way to solve this is `Encoding.default_external = 'BINARY'` (which is an alias for `'ASCII-8BIT'`).

Another way is to run your whole program in a binary locale: `LANG=C ruby doit.rb`.

See [Ruby 1.9's Three Default Encodings](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings), a part of a great series explaining the Unicode situation in Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.